# Devise warden 401 Unauthorized when wrong credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I have a quite standard Devise login procedure with:

View:

resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

```
<%= f.input :password, input_html: {class: "span6"} %>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <p><%= f.check_box :remember_me %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember me</p>
<% end -%>

<input type="hidden" name="after_sign_in_page" value="<%=@after_sign_in_page%>">
<p><%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-success" %></p>
```

And I just created a sessioncontroller to downcase the email:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    params[:user][:email].downcase!
    super
    logger.debug "Errors: #{resource.errors}"
  end
```

A login with good credentials happens fine.

With wrong credentials, It redirects to the sign-in page with this log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-10 09:59:44 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8eytQkr20JOOOdDvpCWakbmUzNoaHMxK9/BSEVxETik=", "user"=>{"email"=>"nicolas@demoreau.be", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "after_sign_in_page"=>"", "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Time zone: (GMT+00:00) UTC, current area: , user to register: , current controller: sessions
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 69ms
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8eytQkr20JOOOdDvpCWakbmUzNoaHMxK9/BSEVxETik=", "user"=>{"email"=>"nicolas@demoreau.be", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "after_sign_in_page"=>"", "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Rendered devise/sessions/_new.html.erb (17.8ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (19.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (66.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 173ms (Views: 98.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Apparently the 401 is dropped by Warden but I couldn't figure out why.
The user is correctly redirected back to the login page but there is no error message displayed (which is normal as they are wiped out by the redirect)

What am I doing wrong?

thanks!

EDIT 1:

For now, I found a quick hack. I added this in SessionsController#new

```
if params[:user]
  flash[:alert] = "Incorrect login or password"
end
```

Not very elegant but at least, I have something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flash message is not going to be set because `Devise::SessionsController#create` calls warden for the authentication which, in case of failures, will call `Devise::FailureApp`. Your controller never handles the failure scenarios.

If you want a custom message, you can customize the failure app for that, there are some articles in the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) explaining how to do so.

But in general, you can customize your failure messages via I18n and there is probably a better way to achieve what you want without a need to override Devise controllers.

Comment: Hi Jose, many thanks for your help! I don't know where you find all this energy. After fighting during hours and hours, I finally found the guilty where I didn't expected it: I had added an additional check in ApplicationController to reset the session if current_user was nil and this was apparently conflicting with Devise... The rest of the config was ok... Aarrgh!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, let me advice you against overriding Devise controllers:

1. In this case, Devise takes care of transforming the email to lower
   case for you, so there's really no need to overwrite the `create` method.
2. Your app will support Devise updates seamlessly if you stick to the
   standard.

Also, Devise should set a flash error automatically, make sure you're displaying it in your view.

The status code 401 is just a standard response for unauthorized requests.

> 401 Unauthorized is similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use
> when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been
> provided
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

You should definitely consider dropping your custom controller,

Cheers

Comment: Maybe, they added the downcase in recent versions of Devise. It's wasn't the case when I added this method in version 1.5 or so. Anyway, I tried dropping the controller but I still don't receive any flash message

Comment: Make sure you're configuring your model correctly https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-models

Comment: Also, the flash messages were there long before, "Devise uses flash messages with I18n with the flash keys :notice and :alert." https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#i18n.  Make sure your view is pointing to the same action as https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb.  In the end it must be a problem with your custom code, perhaps you're doing more than what you show here, pay special attention to additional redirects you perform. See http://bit.ly/V7larc

Answer (score 3):

I agree with jassa, just update your Devise version (with `bundle update devise`).

Case insensitive emails are already present in Devise, just make sure you have this config:

```
# devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email ]
end
```

In any case, since you seem to be missing some flash messages and this config, perhaps it would better if you just re-ran the generator:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

You should then let Devise overwrite some files, just make sure you backup yours first.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. I totally agree with you about insensitive emails but this is not my issue (nor its cause). The issue is about flash[:messages]. I tried to regenerate an install. It didn't help...